# Visual Studio 2022 suddenly stopped showing source file contents

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022

My Visual Studio 2022 accidentally stopped showing source file contents. I can click on a source file, and then i see this:
[image]

Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the application? Closing and reopening the tab? Reloading the project? I'd try all of these and see what happens

Comment: @TimothyG. sorry for a late response. Thanks for your comment, i tried that, none of that worked :c